# Sorting strings in c++ (bubble and selection)

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort, selection-sort

this is my code for sorting integers. It contains two functions, one being a bubble sort and the other a selection sort. Is there a basic way to convert them to string-sorting functions? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int array[], int size){
bool swap;
int temp;

do{
    swap = false;
    for (int count = 0; count < (size - 1); count++){
        if (array[count] > array[count + 1]){
            temp = array[count];
            array[count] = array[count + 1];
            array[count + 1] = temp;
            swap = true;
        }
    }
}while (swap);
}

void selectionSort(int array[], int size){
int startScan, minIndex, minValue;

for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++){
    minIndex = startScan;
    minValue = array[startScan];
    for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++){
        if (array[index] < minValue){
            minValue = array[index];
            minIndex = index;
        }
    }
    array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
    array[startScan] = minValue;
}
}

int main(){
int str[5] = {5, 3, 1, 7, 8};

bubbleSort(str, 5);

selectionSort(str, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. And it's kind of easy. Maybe, you've heard about function [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)(char* ptr1, char* ptr2).

It compares string char-by-char, and returns:

- **0** - if strings are equal
- **<0**  the first character that does not match has a lower value in ptr1 than in ptr2
- **>0**  the first character that does not match has a greater value in ptr1 than in ptr2

So you need to replace this `array[count] > array[count + 1]` with this`strcmp(array[count],array[count+1])>0`. And it's supposed, that your  array is `char* array[]`. If not, it won't work correctly at all.